# Array out of bounds exception, not evident where

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having a trouble while trying to fill an array that I have created.  It seems no matter how I setup the loop it's still throwing the error.  Looking over my code I can't see where I've gone wrong,  can someone throw me a clue?

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

   /*************************************************************************
  * Name        :  
* Username    : 
 * Description :  
 *************************************************************************/



    public class World{

    String fileName;
    Tile[][] map;
    int width,height;
    int x_coor, y_coor;

public World(String inFileName){
    this.fileName = inFileName;

    //Create all the tiles

    try {

        //create the scanner in order to read the file parameters
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        //Get the height and width of the map
        int height, width;
        width = scanner.nextInt();
        height  = scanner.nextInt();
        Tile[][] map = new Tile[width][height];
        //testing
        System.out.println("Width is: " +width);
        System.out.println("Height is: " + height);
        //create blank map
        for(int i = 0; i < height-1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width -1; j++){
                map[i][j] = new Tile("Blank");
                System.out.println("System created point:" + i + j);
            }
        }

        //instantiate the map, and fill it
        for(int i = 0; i < height ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width - 1; j++){
                //Testing code
                System.out.print(j);
                //create tiles
                map[i][j] = new Tile(scanner.next());
            }
            //Testing code
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
         private void draw(){

    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {       


        World world = new World(args[0]);
        world.draw();       
    }   
}
```

Comment: please provide the error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second nested `for` loops (`//instantiate the map, and fill it`) in `for(int i = 0; i < height ; i++)` you didn't decrease `height` in 1

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < height - 1 ; i++)
```

In addition, you mixed `width` and `height` in `Tile[][] map = new Tile[width][height];`. It should be

```
Tile[][] map = new Tile[height][width];
```

Comment: After fixing that it's still throwing an error at


        map[i][j] = new Tile("Blank");

Comment: @Kevin Do you still have problem?

Comment: @Kevin I found the problem. Check the edited answer.